# Test for SOQL in Apex Controller

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, controller

I'm not sure if I'm testing correctly. What check here should be done? Could you help with the test?

```
public class Controller {
    public List<MyTool__c> tools {get;set;}

    public Controller(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
        //The color I'm getting from Account's custom field
        tools = [SELECT Id, Name, Color__c FROM MyTool__c WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY];
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@isTest
public class ControllerTests {

    @isTest
    public static void testSOQL(){
        Account acc = new Account(
            LastName = 'TestAccount',
            Color__c = 'White'
        );
        insert acc;

        MyTool__c tool = new MyTool__c(
            Name = 'Test',
            AccountId__c = acc.Id
        );
        insert tool;

        List<MyTool__c> tools = [SELECT Id, Name, Color__c FROM MyTool__c WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY];

        Test.startTest();  
            PageReference pageRef = Page.WarehousePDF;
            Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
            ApexPages.StandardSetController sc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(tools);
            WarehousePDFController controller = new WarehousePDFController(sc);
            sc.setSelected(tools);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in the controller do you set the color?  You will need to set that property in the test and then assert that the public tools property is what you expect.

Comment: Okay. Thank you!

Comment: @cropredy your comment is more suited as an answer, please consider posting one :)

Answer (score -1):

In your apex class, the only thing you can test, is testing that you have at least ONE tool in your list.

If you want to test the color value (like @cropedy said)... why not, but in your apex class, nothing say that `Color__c` is important to have.

The only thing you have to test (in your exemple) is that your SOQL query retrieve at least one record to avoid an SOQL error;

exemple :

`System.assert(tools.size() > 0);`